# Read XML and Pagination with Angular

Tags: angularjs, xml, pagination

How I can combine this two app or module of angularjs. I have tried everithing but not work.  Here to code:
1) Read and list xml file with ng-repeat
http://rabidgadfly.com/2013/02/angular-and-xml-no-problem/
2)Pagination with angularjs script
http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/GoC5bcFs6HURSOpqeYE8?p=preview

script.js

```
    var SOURCE_FILE = "guitars.xml";

$scope.IMAGE_LOCATION = "http://rabidgadfly.com/assets/angular/xmlload/";

xmlTransform = function(data) {
    console.log("transform data");
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var json = x2js.xml_str2json( data );
    return json.guitars.guitar;
};

setData = function(data) {

    $scope.dataSet = data;
};

DataSource.get(SOURCE_FILE,setData,xmlTransform);
```

index.html

```
        <li dir-paginate="g in dataSet | filter:q | itemsPerPage:     pageSize" current-page="currentPage">{{ g.make }}</li>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I think the code is self-explanatory, if you have specific questions about the code I'd love to add an answer